# Изменит ли оператор ! переменную или только вернёт изменённый результат?

Tags: php

К примеру есть `boolean` переменная `$a = true;` Если написать в следующем шаге так !$a; то изменится ли её значение на `false` или `false` только вернётся в левую часть выражения в то время как значение переменной останется неизменным?

Comment: [слабо попробовать](http://ideone.com/zHcv6u) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор ! ничего не изменяет. С его помощью выполняется конвертирование значения выражения для конструкции `if` (или тернарных операторов или в других редковстречаемых ситуациях). например, чтобы выполнился первый блок `if`, нужно чтобы условие, указанное в скобках вернуло `true`:

```
$a = 0;
if (!$a) {
    echo 'ложь';
} else {
    echo 'истина';
}
```

в данном примере в скобках генерируется false. А оператор ! конвертирует его в true, и поэтому срабатывает первый блок кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = true;
!$a;
var_dump($a); // boolean true

$b = true;
if (!$b) { }
var_dump($b); // boolean true
```